# How to return only one directive between two almost identical ones in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-decorator

How do i include only one directive out of two identical ones, where one has deprecated functionality and other one isn't deprecated?

1. The deprecated one can't be removed (file deleted).
2. I remember there was a way to get all the same-named directives and return an array of them, letting me choose which ones should be returned, but i can't find it anymore.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule');

app.directive('myDirective1',
// returns all the needed things;
);

app.directive('myDirective1',
// returns all the needed things, plus some additional stuff;
);
```

How to return/register only the first myDirective1 without the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way

```
.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    // Returns the second registered uiGridOdataDirective from module,
    // so we dont call the same functionality twice.
    $provide.decorator('uiGridOdataDirective', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        return [ $delegate[1] ];
    }]);
}]);
```